# Can't cast android to tv with Chromecast

Tags: chromecast

I'm trying to cast my android to non smart tv with Chromecast but I really can't.I've tried so many apps like Google Home,Miracast,EzMira but Chromecast does'n show up in the Google Home app at all.This is the Screen on Tv that I get [link](https://ibb.co/WPYc7pm)

Is the chromecast broken?

Edit:I've managed to cast with another Xiaomi phone but I think the Chromecast it' broken because it stays connected for only 2 or 3 seconds and then it disconnects.

Comment: If the "non smart TV" isn't physically connected to a Chromecast dongle device, or the Google Home app doesn't detect your Chromecast device, the Chromecast protocol will not work. Streaming from Android to TV can use different protocols so knowing the right name helps. Your image appears to be a 'miracast' device but you would have to check each Android phone for support: https://www.xda-developers.com/miracast/

Comment: I took the Chromecast to the store where I bought it and they said it was defective and that they would send it for warranty.Maybe that's why it connects for two or three seconds and then disconnects because it was faulty and yes with Samsung M11 I used Miracast and with Xiaomi Redmi 9a I used the default Cast.